Overleaf, note foot and colourful box
I am starting to use Overleaf to do my master thesis.
Could I ask how can I implement this modification for all my pages?:

And how can I add this nice colourful box at the beginning of each chapter ? I manage to add the Lenny package and insert the square but I am not sure how to do this box format identically:

I saw this in a thesis that is not mine but I liked a lot the format hehe
Thank a lot for your time and help.

Here you go:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry} % use this to change the marigin sizes
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % to define custom colours
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % header
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % colourbox
\usepackage{epigrafica} % change font
\usepackage[LGR,OT1]{fontenc} % pick font here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

% define your custom colours
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{0.65, 0.18, 0.13}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.894, 0.961, 0.949}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.576, 0.533}
% define default colour of the box in the left header
\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{myred}{myred}}

\title{Some title}

% Set up headers and footers:
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % this prevents the section name in the header being written in all caps 

%header
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vspace{-8pt}\color{myred}\hrulefill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\fbox{\textcolor{white}{\thepage\hspace{30pt}}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
%footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\large \thepage}

% define the textbox
\tcbset {
  base/.style={
    arc=0mm, % change this if you want the box to be rounded
    bottomtitle=0.5mm,
    boxrule=0mm,
    colback=lightgreen!20!, % background colour
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    left=3.5mm,
    leftrule=2mm, % thickness of the dark green stripe on the left
    right=3.5mm,
    title={#1},
    toptitle=0.75mm, 
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{mainbox}[1]{
  colframe=darkgreen, 
  base={#1}
}

% .----------------.
% | begin document |
% '----------------'
                                                          
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{15pt}
\begin{mainbox}{} 
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mainbox}
\vspace{15pt}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}

Here is what the output looks like:


I am very new using Overleaf and LaTeX but I could solve the first part of my question with this code
% Page style
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Redefine the section title format
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

% Redefine the header style
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
    \node[shape=rectangle, fill=923725, text=white, inner sep=5.5pt, minimum height=0.5pt, minimum width=80pt, text width=80pt, align=left] (char) {\thepage};
    \draw[923725, line width=0.5pt] (char.south west) -- ++(15.26cm,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove the default header rule

% Ensure sections appear in the header
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}


In case it can be useful for others, I know it is not a very deep tough question, but for me, as a new user, it is hehe
I still cannot solve the box problem. Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks!
